# Slow recompilation time when importing SCSS file into another with create react app

Tags: sass, create-react-app, core-ui

I have a project that uses CoreUI and has a file structure that looks like this:

```
src
  /scss
    style.scss
  /components
    /Component
      Component.tsx
      Component.scss
```

The CoreUI library is built on top of Bootstrap and requires the style files to be imported independently. Those files are imported on the `style.scss` file like so:

```
@use '@coreui/coreui/scss/coreui';
@import '@coreui/chartjs/scss/coreui-chartjs';
```

However, when trying to import the first scss file above into `Component.scss` (using the @use directive as well) to reuse Bootstrap classes, the compilation time slows down quite considerably, making it really painful to make changes to any styles. I've already tried to use the `@forward` rule too, as well as importing the `style.scss` file into a partial and importing the partial without success.

There's probably a simple workaround for this but I haven't been able to find it. How can I keep the compilation times short when reusing sass files?

**March 2023 update:** No longer a part of this project, so I am no longer able to post any updates myself. I am leaving the question up for others who might want to see/give an answer in the future

Comment: do you have any solution for this problem?
I have the same =(

Comment: @jon_eldiablo I don't :c. See my update above; hope you find a solution soon.

Comment: I have been using WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) to develop. It already took up to two minutes or more, it was very desperate.
I have stopped using it, using the cmd terminal directly, the compilation time is much less.
so... that's my solution.